# Adapter for two different FFCs? (4 conductors each, but different Cables)

Tags: ffc

I have two different Flexible Flat Cables, both feeding two different touch panel and LCD packages.  I bought a replacement panel that was not the exact same model (the original model is nowhere to be found online), but I can only assume it will work as the model numbers were the same up until the very last couple of digits...and at any rate, I have no datasheet on the device's original LCD, so I couldn't check, I'll just have to try.  Upon receiving the panel, however, the touch panel cable was...different.  The other cables were identical, however (at least physically).  The cables are pictures below.  the B cable is the original, and the A cable is the one that came with the replacement package.  I started reading all that I could find about FFCs and the more I read (including several questions here), the more I realized that I might should ask an expert on the topic since I can't seem to make heads or tails (for the most part) with the information that I found!

In a nutshell, I'd like to find (or build if it's not THAT much trouble) an adapter that will adapt the A cable's end to that of the B cable's end.  There are markings on both cables, but none that turned anything up on google.  Maybe they'll look familiar to someone here though.

A cable: AA1017-43 CTC.

B cable: A0674D

If somebody knows right off just from the picture where I can find an adapter, that would be fantastic, but more than likely, I'll need help identifying them (which apparently involves some measurements) and knowing where to look for the components that I'd need for the adapter...and of course if there's anything I'm not taking into consideration due to my lack of experience on this specific topic!

Thanks very much!

[image: FFC cables A and B]

Comment: You could potentially cut off the B cable and see if you can strip back the covering (from the large end) to expose the traces.  If so, and if the mating connector is able to contact both sides, you may be able to carefully solder a flipped over piece of that onto the new cable as an adapter.  Safer of course would be making a PCB with both matching connectors.  Or this looks large enough that a point to point connection of four fine wires could be feasible.

Comment: Sigh...I got excited to give that a shot, and then I realized that I broke one of the four contacts on connector B's cable (you can just see it, the very right one, near the contacts).  I had another assembly, but it was all busted up so I threw it away and just took out the trash a bit ago.  I...might dig it back out though and give this a shot haha